# How to save a query result as int type

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, web

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand com4;
        string str5 = "SELECT count(gid) as count from [Committee].[dbo].[group] ;";
        com4 = new SqlCommand(str5, con);
        SqlDataReader reader4 = com4.ExecuteReader();
        int count;
        if (reader4.Read())
        {
            count = (int) reader4["count"].ToString;
            reader4.Close();
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) //(count instead of 6)
```

Hello guys, I have this code i am expecting an int type from this query result to use it in for loop, so the question is how to read it as int and save it in count variable?
I hope you got my idea.

Best regards.

Comment: what happens when you run this code?

Comment: I can not use a fixed value in the loop I need to get the value from the database so I use it in the for loop.

Comment: Okay... What happens when you get the result back from the Database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, according to your SQL statement and code, you only care about the first row of the first column you should use `ExecuteScalar()` to save from opening a reader. Then `Convert.ToInt32` to handle the conversion. Your code will then look like this:

```
com4 = new SqlCommand(str5, con);
int count = Convert.ToInt32(com4.ExecuteScalar());

for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++){
    // Code here ... //
}
```